# $_SESSION cargar página PHP sin datos

Tags: php, html, session

Tengo un problema a la hora de tratar una página PHP.

Dispongo de un `formulario` en "**reservar.php**" que una vez insertados ciertos datos, se muestra un `div` y dentro de ese `div` existen varias posibilidades/disponibilidades para poder realizar una reserva **si elegimos una reserva disponible** nos lleva a "**confirmacion_reserva.php**" cargando los datos de la reserva elegida, obviamente todo esto con un usuario registrado con el típico `logueo` en una `web` y dándole el saludo oportuno "**Bienvenido usuario1**".

El problema viene a la hora de actualizar la página "**confirmación_reserva.php**", debido a que si actualizamos, ya no contiene los datos del anterior **.php** (**reservar.php**) de dentro proceden todos los datos.

Quiero que cuando no exista una sesión o inicio de sesión `$_SESSION` o no se hayan podido enviar los datos, la página (si la cargamos `F5`) nos redirija a "**iniciar_sesion_cliente.php**".

**reservar.php**

```
<?php
//Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
session_start();
//Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
    $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function() {
                var defaults = {
                    closeText: 'Cerrar', 
                    prevText: '<Anterior', 
                    nextText: 'Siguiente>', 
                    currentText: 'Hoy', 
                    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'], 
                    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'], 
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'], 
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'], 
                    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'], 
                    weekHeader: 'Sm', 
                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', 
                    firstDay: 1, 
                    isRTL: false, 
                    showMonthAfterYear: false, 
                    yearSuffix: '' 
                }; 

                $.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults); 

                $("#check_in").datepicker({
                    minDate: 0, //The value "0" means today (0 days from today). 
                    onSelect: function(dateStr) { 
                        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //Día actual. 
                        if (minDate) { 
                            //Se comprueba si existe una fecha de salida.
                            var maxDate = $("#check_out").datepicker('getDate'); 
                            if (maxDate && minDate < maxDate) {} else { 
                                //Si existe una fecha de salida y es menor a la fecha de entrada.
                            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1); 
                            //Se cambia la fecha al día siguiente del seleccionado en la fecha de entrada.
                            $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate). 
                            datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate); //Día siguiente al actual en "check_out". 
                        } 
                    } 
                    $('#check_out').change(); //Activar el evento "onchange". 
                    $('#check_out').prop("disabled", false); //Se activa la fecha de salida.
                } 
            }); 

            $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) { 
                console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>

<body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
    <div class="sesion_cliente">
        <?php 
        //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
        if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
            echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido ".$cliente."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</p></a>";
            //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
            if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                //Redireccionamos a la página "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php" en 0 segundos.
                header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div id="contenedor">
        <div class="busqueda">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">
                <!--<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#check_in").blur(function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#42F508");
                });
                </script>-->
                <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                <p id="calculoNoches"></p><br/>

                <label for="personas"><b>Personas:</b></label>
                <?php
                echo "<select name='personas'>";
                for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                    if($i==2){
                        echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>


        <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
            <?php
            include_once "Clases/BD.php";
            //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
            if(isset($_POST["buscar"]) && $_POST["check_in"]!="" && $_POST["check_out"]!=""){
                $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
                $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
                //Llamamos al método "obtenerCabanasPorFecha" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                $datos = BD::obtenerCabanasPorFecha($check_in, $check_out);
                echo "<br/>";
                foreach($datos as $cabana){
                    echo "<b>".$cabana->getNombre()."</b>";
                    //Campo hidden (oculto) donde guardamos un valor que NO queremos mostrar.
                    echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='idcabana' value='".$cabana->getIdcabana()."'/>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='check_in' value='".$check_in."'/>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='check_out' value='".$check_out."'/>";
                        echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' value='Reservar'/></center>";
                    echo "</form>";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    //Cargamos las imágenes en un array $imagenes.
                    $imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
                    foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
                        echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='210' height='210'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                    echo "<br/>";
                    $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCabana($cabana->getIdcabana());
                        foreach ($opiniones as $comentario){
                            $fecha = new DateTime($comentario["fecha"]);
                            echo "<br/><div id='opiniones'>".$fecha->format ('d/m/Y')."(".$comentario["idemail"].") - ".$comentario["opinion"]."</div><br/>";
                        }
                    echo "<hr/>";
                    echo "<br/>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**confirmacion_reserva.php**

```
<?php
    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Confirmación reserva</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_confirmacion.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        echo"<br/>";
        //Si no existe la variable de sesión...
        if(!isset($_SESSION["cliente"])){
            //echo "<center><h2>¡Debes iniciar sesión antes de reservar!</h2></center>";
            //Refrescamos la página a los 0 segundos.
            header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
        //Si existe la variable de sesión...
        }else{
            //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
            if(isset($_POST["reservar"])){
                $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
                $idemail = $_SESSION["cliente"];
                $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
                $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
                echo "<div id='detalles_reserva'>";
                    echo 
                    "<img src='imagenes/cabaña.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabaña: ".$idcabana."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/email.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: ".$idemail."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Check_in'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_in: ".$check_in."
                    <br/><br/>".
                    "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Check_out'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_out: ".$check_out."<br/><br/>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
            <form action="reservar.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="image" src='imagenes/atras.png' height='20px' width='26px' name="atras" id="atras" onclick="javascript:history.back();"/>
            </form>
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <form action="pagar.php" name="mipagar" id="mipagar" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="image" src='imagenes/pagar.png' height='20px' width='26px' name="pagar" id="pagar"/>
            </form>
        <?php
        }
        //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "confirmar"...
        if(isset($_POST["confirmar"])){
            //Llamamos al método "realizarReserva" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
            BD::realizarReserva($idcabana, $idemail, $check_in, $check_out);
        }
        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**¿Por qué si recargo la página con f5, sin traer datos de reservar.php, me salen los botones y no me redirige a "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php"?**

**Imagen demostrativa CON DATOS:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen demostrativa SIN DATOS:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cambia `header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");` por `header('Location: iniciar_sesion_cliente.php');`

Comment: @EduenSarceño Me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
    <?php
    echo"<br/>";
    //Si no existe la variable de sesión...
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cliente"])) {
        //echo "<center><h2>¡Debes iniciar sesión antes de reservar!</h2></center>";
        //Refrescamos la página a los 0 segundos.
        header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
        //Si existe la variable de sesión...
    } else {
        //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
        if (isset($_POST["reservar"])) {
            $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
            $idemail = $_SESSION["cliente"];
            $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
            $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
            echo "<div id='detalles_reserva'>";
            echo
            "<img src='imagenes/cabaña.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabaña: " . $idcabana . "
                <br/><br/>" .
            "<img src='imagenes/email.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: " . $idemail . "
                <br/><br/>" .
            "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Check_in'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_in: " . $check_in . "
                <br/><br/>" .
            "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Check_out'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_out: " . $check_out . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        else{
            header("Location: reservar.php");
        }
        ?>
        <form action="reservar.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="image" src='imagenes/atras.png' height='20px' width='26px' name="atras" id="atras" onclick="javascript:history.back();"/>
        </form>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <form action="pagar.php" name="mipagar" id="mipagar" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="image" src='imagenes/pagar.png' height='20px' width='26px' name="pagar" id="pagar"/>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "confirmar"...
    if (isset($_POST["confirmar"])) {
        //Llamamos al método "realizarReserva" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        BD::realizarReserva($idcabana, $idemail, $check_in, $check_out);
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

Comment: yo creo que es por que la session cliente aún está, pero ($_POST["reservar"])) no llega por ende solo mostrará los botones. editaré la respuesta por si es...

Comment: Yo creo que también puede ser por lo que tú dices. Igual al pulsar F5, aún la sesión está guardada y la coge... Pensé que pulsando F5, o bien Ctrl+F5 para borrar la caché, la eliminaría.

Comment: Creo que tu edicción no es el todo completa, debido a que si, pulso F5 o recargo la página no me vuelve a "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php" sino a "reservar.php" de nuevo, volviéndome a cargar la sesión anterior.

Comment: Sí, también es buena idea, para que vuelva atrás... o también se podría hacer que muestre un error del tipo "Error404 o página no deseada" y a los 2-3 segundos vuelva a reservar.php

Comment: Como lo veo yo: Te debería devolver a iniciar session si es que la session no está iniciada, pero si esta iniciada y va directamente a confirmacion_reserva.php y no se ha hecho ninguna reserva, devuelve a reservar.php. (?).
si quieres que al presionar F5 vuelva a iniciar session aún así con la session iniciada:
en el else que agregué inserta  unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
y el header al login.

Comment: Edita la respuesta totalmente para poder entenderlo de tu manera. Donde edites pon, para fijarme, un comentario /* */

Answer (score 0):

Confirmación reserva

```
<body>
    <?php
    echo"<br/>";
    //Si no existe la variable de sesión...
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cliente"])){
        //echo "<center><h2>¡Debes iniciar sesión antes de reservar!</h2></center>";

        // header() se utiliza en la cabecera, antes de cualquier código HTML, esto algunas veces produce problemas cuando no se respeta.
        // Aquí te entrego una alternativa para HTML after con JS
        echo "<script>location.href='iniciar_sesion_cliente.php';</script>";

        //Refrescamos la página a los 0 segundos.
        // header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
    //Si existe la variable de sesión...
    }else{
        //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "Reservar"...
        if(isset($_POST["reservar"])){
            $idcabana = $_POST["idcabana"];
            $idemail = $_SESSION["cliente"];
            $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
            $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
            echo "<div id='detalles_reserva'>";
                echo
                "<img src='imagenes/cabaña.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabaña: ".$idcabana."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/email.png' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Cabaña'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email: ".$idemail."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Check_in'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_in: ".$check_in."
                <br/><br/>".
                "<img src='imagenes/calendario.jpg' height='22px' width='22px' alt='Check_out'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check_out: ".$check_out."<br/><br/>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>
        <form action="reservar.php" name="mireserva" id="mireserva" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="image" src='imagenes/atras.png' height='20px' width='26px' name="atras" id="atras" onclick="javascript:history.back();"/>
        </form>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <form action="pagar.php" name="mipagar" id="mipagar" method="POST" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="image" src='imagenes/pagar.png' height='20px' width='26px' name="pagar" id="pagar"/>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
    //Si existe y hemos pulsado el botón "confirmar"...
    if(isset($_POST["confirmar"])){
        //Llamamos al método "realizarReserva" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
        BD::realizarReserva($idcabana, $idemail, $check_in, $check_out);
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Posiblemente el error es generado por el uso de la función header() después de la existencia de código. En teoría esta función se debe utilizar antes que cualquier código (en la primera línea). Esto a veces produce problemas al funcionar y es por ello que si se respeta su uso (antes de cualquier código) no debería dejar de funcionar.

Para el caso donde ya se haya utilizado código antes, existe una solución práctica con JavaScript la cual también se le puede entregar delay, pero como aquí era de "0", no vi necesario colocarlo en tu archivo. Con eso el redireccionamiento no debería presentarte ningún problema de acuerdo a la condición de tu if.

En todo caso, aquí te creo una función JS para definir el tiempo para que se produzca el redireccionamiento (variable en milisegundos):

```
function redireccionamiento() { 
document.location.href=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php;}
setTimeout("redireccionamiento()", 1000);
```

También te recuerdo que F5 (actualizar/refrescar) no es suficiente para dejar de contar con una sesión previamente iniciada puesto que la sesión queda en la caché y por ende debes vaciar esa memoria de tu navegador antes de ejecutar pruebas para verificar con certeza.

Espero haberte podido ser útil.

Un cordial saludo!